# Why doesn't this image center in a fixed-width DIV?

Tags: html, css

I know I'm missing something obvious here... the DIV has a fixed width, the image has a fixed width, this should be a snap...

```
<style>
  .featured {margin:0 auto;}
</style>
<div style='width:300px;border:solid 1px red;'>
    <img src='http://www.musicalads.co.uk/img/articles/image_64.jpg'
         class='featured' style='width:186px;height:215px;'>
</div>
```

You can play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/AHjAk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll also need to add `display: block;` to the image if you plan on centering it using `auto` for its left/right margins

http://jsfiddle.net/AHjAk/1/

Comment: [Here is the same, but with all external styles](http://jsfiddle.net/AHjAk/3/). Inline styles are generally frowned upon if at all avoidable, @Eric.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree. This isn't my "real" code, it's just something simple I put together to demonstrate the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

or try this simple `text-align:center;` the container
http://jsfiddle.net/AHjAk/2/

```
 <div style='width:300px;border:solid 1px red;text-align:center'>
<img src='http://www.musicalads.co.uk/img/articles/image_64.jpg' class='featured'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `text-align:center` to the parent gif that should center the image.

```
<style>
  .featured {margin:0 auto;}
</style>
<div style='width:300px;border:solid 1px red;text-align:center'>
    <img src='http://www.musicalads.co.uk/img/articles/image_64.jpg'
         class='featured' style='width:186px;height:215px;'>
</div>
```

And if you want to center that parent div itself, your body needs a `text-align:center`.